# Observe the Room database 'insert' callback

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

How can we get the callback for the 'insert' operation in repository as Livedata and I can pass back to viewmodel using coroutines?

Dao

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(user : User): Long
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you need callback if you use coroutines in your code.

If you make your `insert` function as suspend, you can call it from your ViewModel from inside coroutine (for example with [viewModelScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope)). And inside this coroutine you'll move to the next line of code only after `insert` method would be done:

```
viewModelScope.launch{
   val userId = repository.insert(someUser)
   // <- there coroutine is suspended until insert is done. In a sense it's like a callback
   someOtherMethod()   
}
```